# Not understanding what this error in React / WebPack mean

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-design-lite

So I'm trying to move an existing static site that has Material Design Lite into React.

I use the Create-React-App package to create a new react app. I run the command "npm i 'material-design-lite' --save" - this both works.

Now, in my App.JS file I import it in.

```
import componentHandler from 'material-design-lite';

class App extends Component {

   componentDidMount() {
    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
  }
```

When I do, I get this error

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_material_design_lite___default.a.upgradeAllRegistered is not a function

and it is complaining at the line componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();

The thing is though this function does exist. I can access it when I'm debugging, I can also access it in the chrome console.

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library is not prepared for being used as an es6 module. Your import statement imports an empty object because `material-design-lite` does not export anything.

You could just import the module like this:

```
import 'material-design-lite';
```

This attaches the `componentHandler` object to the `window` object.
You can access it via `window.componentHandler`. You just have to make sure to do the import before accessing it anywhere in your app.

Comment: thanks that worked. For reference, how do I know whether something is es5 or es6? Is it just a matter of looking through the node_modules and reading the code or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can only really see this from the sources. You can also go with try and error if you aren't sure if it is modularized. Just import the module into an object and log it to see if there is something inside. If it's not that usually means it's not supported. As far as i can see from the [mdl github repo](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite) they moved to another library that supports es6 modules. See [Material Components for the web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web). That may even suit your project better.